# A question about the right statistical test

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics, frequency

let's say that I have a table as follows

```
            SSE1  SSE2  SSE3  SSE4  SSE5
frequncy     125   200   259   300   200
```

and I want to see if there is a significant difference between these frequency numbers. What test to use ? I am thinking chisquared test. Thanks

Comment: Chi-square test.

Comment: Do we use the same test if our values were percentages ? And what is the null hypothesis ?

Comment: Use the raw counts, not percentages.  There is more information in using raw counts.  The null hypothesis will depend on your research question.  Most software will use the null hypothesis that the categories are equally frequent (i.e. that the frequency for each cell is 1/number of total cells).  This doesn't have to be the case, you can use whatever null frequency distribution you feel is appropriate for your research question.